# Converting data form for 2mode network in r

Tags: r, social-networking

The data(excel) that I have looks like this:

---

[image: Excel]

---

I have 2600 movies in the first column and there are names of directors and staffs in other columns. Some names appear several times.

I'm having trouble converting this excel data to a format that I can perform two-mode network analysis(event: movie, ties from those movies) in r. Are there any helping documents or codes that I can convert this data to a proper format?

Comment: Not sure I understand your required output format - what does "ties from those movies" mean?

Comment: can you show the required sample output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `igraph` (which calls this type of network *bipartite*).

Assume you have created a data frame with your excel data in it, called dt.

```
dt
     Movie     director codirector staff1
1 StarWars     JJAbrams       <NA>   Anne
2  Abarter JamesCameron       <NA>   <NA>
3   Loiter         Kenn      Klark   Kage
```

Then you  can create a bipartite graph, `g` as follows:

library(reshape2)

```
edgelist <- melt(dt, id.vars = 'Movie')[, -2]
edgelist <- edgelist[complete.cases(edgelist), ]

library(igraph)

g <- graph.data.frame(edgelist)

V(g)$type <-  V(g)$name %in% edgelist[, 1]
g
plot(g)
IGRAPH DN-B 9 6 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), type (v/l)
+ edges (vertex names):
[1] StarWars->JJAbrams     Abarter ->JamesCameron Loiter  ->Kenn         Loiter  ->Klark       
[5] StarWars->Anne         Loiter  ->Kage
```

[image]

In `igraph` a bipartite graph is a regular graph with each vertex having a type attribute set to `TRUE/FALSE`. It doesn't matter which type of vertex is which, in this case Movies are set to `TRUE`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It helped a lot!